# Should I use asp.net Mvc with Angular 4 Cli ?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular

I am a beginner to angular4 wanted to integrate angular with asp.net MVC,
Should I use the only Angular to develop web Application or with MVC ?

Answer (score 1):

AngularJS is a Client Side web (for browser) development framework, and it has nothing to do with the server-side stuff (eg. database related operations or managing user session).

You can use ASP.NET MVC with angular, but it's a good practice to use WEB API, because the View part from MVC will be taking care by the angular framework.

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't be a problem.  You'll need to add a json api to your .net app but people do it all the time.  As with everything, right tools for the right job though.